# Make a char behave like a 'space', in math mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, catcodes

Some may find it a terrible idea, but I have tried to use the dot `.` to behave like a space in math mode.

The idea is to be able to write `\cos.x` or, more generally, `\macro.x` rather than `\macro{x}` or `\macro x`.

I haven't succeeded. One failed idea was to try to change the `\catcode` of `.` to `9`, only in math mode.

It's easy, case by case, to make `\macro.` (with dot) behave like `\macro` -- but that's not the point.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is: if you type `\cos x` you will automatically get a thi space between the two objects.

Comment: @egreg. The point is just for "readability". `\macro.x` is more visible than `\macro x`, and lighter on the eye than `\macro{x}`

Comment: And what do you do when you need a real period in math mode?

Comment: I have yet to use a real period in a paper! It should be switchable (presumably, in the preamble). You, @egreg, are the one who can surely answer this question!

Comment: You wrote, "Some may find it a terrible idea". Yup, quite a few will agree. :-)

Comment: Besides, `\dot x` or `\mathcal A` are wrong syntax and should be `\dot{x}` and `\mathcal{A}`. So I really don't understand what the use would be: I find `\cos x` perfectly readable and `\cos.x` much less.

Comment: @egreg. Let's say it a TeX coding question.

Comment: Why the idea to change the catcode of dot to 9 failed? The `\cos.x` is exactly the same as `\cos x` after such setting and it is what you want.

Comment: Isn't it better to configure your editor to explicitly show spaces, if possible? Then you will not make your files incompatible with others tex files.

Comment: @wipet. One should only change the catcode in math mode. Not in the whole text!

Comment: @rlsx Changing the catcode would not succeed if you want to use `amsmath`, because the contents of the environments are read before the category code change can take effect. Unless quite heavy surgery is done to `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg. I agree. Another idea is to give the dot `.`  `\mathcode` `"8000`. But with which macro assignment? I see that the `space` character, in math, in `amsmath`, or in the Latex class `article`, has ` \mathcode` `"8000`.

Comment: @rlsx That would obviously work for `\cos.x`, but definitely not for `\dot.x` which you seem to like (and shouldn't); just set the active period to `\space` or `\empty`.

Comment: @egreg `space` is math-active. And  "`\macro x`"  works. Why can't the same be accomplished with `.` (or any other non-special character)?

Comment: @rlsx In `\macro x` there is no space as far as tokens are concerned: spaces after control words such as `\macro` are ignored/discarded when transforming the input into tokens.

Comment: @egreg. So what I am asking for is impossible? I thought _rien n'est impossible en_ TeX!   :-)

Comment: @rlsx As I've already said, `\dot x` is *wrong* syntax, even if it gives the result you want. You can use it, if you so like, but it's still unclear and error prone.

Comment: @egreg, I agree it's wrong syntax. I am just using that as an illustation of what I was trying to do with `.`  ...

Comment: @rlsx your comment above to egreg is wrong: space is not math active (which is usually taken to mean `\mathcode"8000` as in wipet's answer) and `\macro x` has no space token the space character is never made into a character token with a catcode, it is simply absorbed while parsing `\cos`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I retract that. I thought that, at some point, I had verified that space is math-active. I was certainly wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: About your comment "_space is not mathactive_", why does the following simple code yield **32768** (i.e. **hex 8000**)? Thanks. `\documentclass{article} \begin{document}\the\mathcode32 \end{document}`

Comment: @rlsx in case math is in the scope of `\@makeother\ ` , that is the texbook says `A mathcode is relevant only when the corresponding category code is 11 or~12;`  so the mathcode of a normal catcode 10 space is never consulted.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle for enlightening a TeX beginner. Where can one see a use of `\@makeother\ ` ?

Comment: @rlsx probbaly nowhere but plain tex has always set that mathcode "just in case" and latex follows suite

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use dot in spacial way only in math mode, you can define it as math-cative, i.e. its mathcode is "8000 and it expands to nothing.

```
\mathcode`.="8000
{\catcode`.=13 \gdef.{}}

$\cos.x$ is the same as $\cos x$.

\bye
```

Comment: I am not familiar with plain tex. But I think it won't work, in general, for `\macro.x`.

Comment: @rlsx What wipet has done is completely transferrable to the LaTeX context.  Per your request, it only applies in math mode.  As many have said, it is not a good idea.  But it indeed provides what you requested.

Comment: @rlsx why don't you try it rather than saying it will not work?, this will work (also in latex) (although there is no reason to do it as simply using `\cos x`  is better in all respects)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes. What Iam saying is that @wipet's suggestion **doesn't work** for a general `\macro{x}` other than `\cos`, `\sin` etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: What I mean is that @wipet's suggestion **doesn't work** for a general `\macro{x}` other than `\cos`, `\sin` etc.

Comment: @rlsx ah OK you can't have a token between a macro and its argument.

Comment: @rlsx If you want to interpret `\macro.x` like `\macro x`, then you must set catcode of dot to 9. You can do this in `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` token lists, if the veature is needed only in math mode.

Answer (score 1):

You want to purposefully tweak TeX syntax.

While doing something like

```
\mathchardef\period=\mathcode`.
\mathcode`.="8000
\begingroup\lccode`~=`. \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{}
```

will allow you to type `\cos.x` and get the same as `\cos x`, this won't do any good to something like `\mathcal.A`.

The big difference is that `\cos` is a parameterless macro, whereas `\mathcal` or `\dot` or any math accent (just by way of example) are one argument macros and TeX will take `.` as the argument, because the macro is not followed by a brace `{`.

Note that the syntax used *consistently* in the LaTeX manual is `\mathcal{A}` or `\dot{x}` and so on. For *good reasons*.

If you want to pursue that path, you're free to do it, but you need to redefine all one-argument macros in math mode that would “benefit” from this ambiguous syntax in such a way that they look forward for a period and if they find it, discard it.

Something like

```
\NewCommandCopy\mathcal@original\mathcal
\DeclareRobustCommand\mathcal{%
  \@ifnextchar.{\@firstoftwo{\mathcal@original}}{\mathcal@original}%
}
```

so `\@firstoftwo{\mathcaloriginal}.` would remove the period and leave `\mathcaloriginal`.

This for *every* such command. Just to have a disputable syntax: I'm firmly convinced that `\dot{x}` and `\mathcal{A}` are *much* better. And that `\cos x` is even clearer than `\cos.x`, because it's like the standard rendering.

The alternative way of setting the catcode of `.` to 9 with the help of `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` will not work if the formula is in the argument to another command.

Comment: I agree with your last statement, as I have tried that earlier.  "_You want to purposefully tweak TeX syntax_." Not quite as bad **egreg**, but I have seen much hairy'er stuff done in this forum, I was curious to see if this could be done. (Sorry but I will be away for a couple of hours.)